# Show $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with at least two (distinct) subgroups of index $2$, and suppose that at least one of the index-$2$ subgroups of $G$ is simple. Prove that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I am pretty stuck on this problem. I know that subgroups of index $2$ are normal. I also know that since they intersect trivially, that their elements commute with one another, but I'm not sure where to go in terms of proving the isomorphism.

Comment: If $H, K$ are these subgroups, then clearly $G \cong H \times K$ by your observations. But $G/H = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $G/K = \mathbb{Z}_2$. Can you conclude that $H = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $K = \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $H$ and $K$ subgroups of $G$ with index $2$, and $H$ is simple. As you observed, $H\cap K = \{e\}$ by the second isomorphism theorem. The second isomorphism theorem also tells us that

- $H\subsetneq HK\subseteq G$ is a subgroup of $G$, and in particular $HK = G$.
- $HK/K\cong H/(H\cap K)$ is a group isomorphism. We now have $G/K\cong H$. But the group $G/K$ has order $2$ and this forces $H\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Exchanging the order of $H$ and $K$ tells us that $K\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ in an analogous fashion.

In particular, we have $G = HK$ and $H\cap K = \{e\}$, so $G = H\times K$ is a direct product.

---

**Edit**: Elaboration on OP's questions

- Since $H$ and $K$ are distinct, then $HK$ must be strictly bigger than $H$, so it has index less than $2$, therefore it must have index $1$, but by definition this means $G = HK$.
- We used the condition of a simple group when showing $H\cap K = \{e\}$. By the second isomorphism theorem, we have $H\cap K \lhd H$ is a normal subgroup, but $H$ is a simple group, so $H\cap K$ is either $H$ or the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$. But $H\cap K\neq H$, otherwise $H\subseteq K$, and since they have the same index this means $H = K$, contradiction. Therefore, $H\cap K = \{e\}$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you conclude that $HK = G$. I understand that $HK$ is a subgroup since $HK = KH$. I am also not sure how one of the subgroups being simple comes into play here.

Comment: @Important_man74 $HK$ is a subgroup strictly larger than $H$, and smaller or equal to $G$; by Lagrange theorem, this forces the index of $HK$ to be $1$. As for your second question, we used the condition of simple group when proving $H\cap K = \{e\}$: $H\cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ by the second isomorphism theorem, so it is either trivial or $H$, but $H\cap K = H$ means $H\subseteq K$, but they have the same index so that gives $H = K$ which is a contradiction, hence $H\cap K = \{e\}$.

Comment: thanks so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Call $H$ and $K$ the two subgroups. They are both normal (as of index $2$) and intersect trivially (as the intersection of normal subgroups is normal, and either $H$ or $K$ is simple). Therefore, $G\cong H\times K$ (because, *e.g.*, $H<H\times K$, and there's no room for proper subgroups of $G$ of order greater than $|H|$). Say $n:=|H|=|K|$, it must then be $|G|=n^2=2n$, whence $n=2$ and hence $G\cong C_2\times C_2$.